# Chai.request is not a function

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

I have the following simple code

```
import app from '../src/app';
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('Get /', () => {
    it('Should say hi there', async () => {
        const response = chai.request(app).get('/');
        console.log(response);
        expect(5).to.equal(5);
    });
});
```

Each time I run

```
mocha -r ts-node/register lib/tests/**/sample.spec.ts
```

I get the following error

> TypeError: chai.request is not a function

I looked at the other stackoverflow posts with the same question. They all said that adding

```
chai.use(chaiHttp)
```

should fix the problem

But, as you can see I already have that.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you try importing like this: `import chai from "chai";`

Answer (score 1):

1. If the `esModuleInterop` is `false` in your `tsconfig.json`, it should work fine.

```js
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('Get /', () => {
  it('Should say hi there', async () => {
    expect(chai.request).to.be.a('function');
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  Get /
    ✓ Should say hi there


  1 passing (4ms)
```

2. If the `esModuleInterop` is `true`, you should use `import chai from 'chai';` instead of using `import * as chai from 'chai';`

Answer (score 0):

use chai-http with chai

```
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
```

then
`chai.use(chaiHttp);`
this works for me.